# Number of roots between $–\pi$ and $\pi$ of the equation $\frac{2}{3} \sin x\cdot x=1$ is

Tags: graphing-functions, problem-solving

Number of roots between $–\pi$ and $\pi$ of the equation
$\frac{2}{3} x\sin x = 1$ is

*My Work:-*

Plotting $y = \sin x$ & $xy = \frac{3}{2}$

I am getting 4 roots. How to conclude it without plotting graph?

*for reference https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jap0g2ju31*

Comment: Can you please write the body of your question in a more readable form?

Comment: Are $\pi$ and $-\pi$ included?

Comment: @Knight it does not matter.$\sin\pi=0$, so the left hand side is $0\ne 1$

Comment: Perhaps look at $\sin x-\frac3{2x}=0$

Comment: It seems a rather tough equation, in either form (multiplicative or additive). Perhaps differentiating several times...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $y=\sin x$ is concave down on $[0,\pi]$ while the curve $y=3/(2x)$ is concave up. Thus they can intersect at most twice on $[0,\pi]$. Since $\sin0=0\lt\infty=\lim_{x\to0}3/(2x)$, $\sin(\pi/2)=1\gt3/\pi=3/(2\pi/2)$, and $\sin(\pi)=0\lt3/(2\pi)$, the curves do intersect twice on $[0,\pi]$. By symmetry, they intersect twice on $[-\pi,0]$ as well, hence there are four roots in all.

Comment: That is an interesting solution! Would you have a simple argument to sustain your first assumption regarding intersection of concave / convex maps?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, thanks for asking!  By definition, a concave down/up curve lies strictly above/below any line connecting two points on the curve, on the interval between the two points. So if an up curve intersected a down curve three times, one of the intersections would be between the other two, which can't happen.

Comment: @BarryCipra a concave up/down curve always lies strictly below any line connecting two points on the curve, I am not getting your line though,cocavity means it's tangent lies below the curve

Comment: @Integralcalculus, I'm not saying anything about a tangent line, just that when you connect the line connecting the two "outer" points of intersection, the curves lie strictly on either side of it in between, so there can't be a third, "inner" point of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As the map $f(x) =\frac{2}{3}\sin x \cdot x$ is even, it is sufficient to prove that there are exactly two solutions on $(0,\pi]$ as $0$ is not a solution.

Then $a$ is solution if and only if $\frac{2}{3} \sin a =\frac{1}{a}$.

$g(x) = \frac{2}{3} \sin x - \frac{1}{x}$ is increasing (difference of an increasing and a decreasing map) on $(0,\pi/2]$ from $-\infty$ to $2/3-2/\pi >0$ hence have a unique solution  on this interval.

Remains to find a simple argument on why there is also only one solution on the interval $[\pi/2, \pi]$. Proving that one exists being easy as $\sin \pi=0$.